# Can we use Paypal Express Checkout with "Ship to multiple address" option

Tags: magento, paypal

We are using Paypal express Checkout using onepage checkout option in Magento. Its working fine and now, I am trying to use the same inside "Ship to multiple address" option.

Based upon my research, I am not sure whether it is possible or not.

So, My question is - Can we use Paypal Express checkout in case of Multishipping option?

I tried to enable (by setting the below data member to True)

```
protected $_canUseForMultishipping      = false;
```

in Payment method model class which result in display of the payment method in the payment section but never redirected to Paypal window instead displayed error on clicking place order:

```
PayPal gateway has rejected request. Invalid token (#10410: Invalid token).
```

Any quick help would be highly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not supported and many others have had this same problem.

See: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16628/multiple-checkout-payment-gateway-redirection-issue/16644#16644

Comment: Thanks for the help..Do you know any URL either on Paypal or Magento website that can verify this fact?